# wildfly-swarm project-stabes-yml configre jms-bridge

Tags: wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to configure a jms-bridge for Wildfy Swarm in the project-stages.yml file, but without success.

Someone would be kind to tell me how I have to proceed?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have tried that isn't working?

Comment: swarm:
    messaging-activemq:
       servers:
          default:
             jms-bridge:
                source:
                   destination: "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/testingQueue"
                   connection-factory: ConnectionFactory

Comment: target:
                   target-context:
                      property:
                         name: java.naming.factory.initial
                         value: "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"

Comment: property:
                         name: java.naming.provider.url
                         value: "t3://sapvxs015:7676"
                      property:
                         name: java.naming.security.principal
                         value: xxxx                         
                      property:
                         name: java.naming.security.credentials
                         value: xxx

Comment: destination: richiesteDownloadQueue
                connection-factory: richiesteDownloadQCF
                name: wls-bridge
                module: com.oracle.ojdbc
                quality-of-service: ONCE_AND_ONLY_ONCE
                failure-retry-interval: 10000
                max-retries: 10
                max-batch-size: 500
                max-batch-time: 50
                add-messageID-in-header: true

Comment: Could you update the question, it's a little hard to follow the yaml snippet